# XMLHttpRequest and Bing translator

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, bing-api

If the following code I don't get `status 200` and `responseText`. But this URL works: `http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate?appId=F1B50AB0743B541AA8C07089042D7B57E9B28D25`. Also in Wireshark I see that I get `status 200` and `data` which is expected. What is the problem with my Javascript code?

```
function btnclick()
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var str = "";
    http.open('GET', 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate?appId=F1B50AB0743B541AA8C07089042D7B57E9B28D25',
    true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function (evt)
    {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make a cross domain XHR. That violates [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You could build a server side proxy, and request that with XHR.

Comment: So from my web page on client side I cannot originate requests? Only via server which can remove "Origin: " header?

Comment: @Igor Server doesn't need to send any different headers, the same origin policy is a browser sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing AJAX, you might want to use the AJAX version to overcome the cross domain issue.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512404.aspx